# Golang string formatting gives unexpected spacing

Tags: go

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
fmt.Printf("Total Calories: %2.f (%2.f%%)\n", item.calorie.TotalCalories, item.calorie.TotalCalories/dailyCalorie*100)
```

It is supposed to output:

```
Total Calories: 150 (5%)
```

But instead I get a spacing between the start of the paranthesis and the number 5, like this:

```
Total Calories: 150 ( 5%)
```

I don't understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%2.f` is giving a default width of 2. You can try just `%f`.

> Width is specified by an optional decimal number immediately preceding
>   the verb. If absent, the width is whatever is necessary to represent
>   the value. Precision is specified after the (optional) width by a
>   period followed by a decimal number. If no period is present, a
>   default precision is used. A period with no following number specifies
>   a precision of zero. Examples:

```
%f     default width, default precision
%9f    width 9, default precision
%.2f   default width, precision 2
%9.2f  width 9, precision 2
%9.f   width 9, precision 0
```

You can read the documentation [here.](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)